# Metaclass not being called in subclasses

Tags: python, metaclass

Here is a python session.

```
>>> class Z(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print cls
        print name
        return type(name, bases, attrs)
...     
>>> class Y(object):
    __metaclass__ = Z
...     
<class '__main__.Z'>
Y
>>> class X(Y):
...     pass
... 
>>> class W(Y):
...     __metaclass__ = Z
...     
<class '__main__.Z'>
W
>>>
```

After I define class X I expect Z._new__ to be called for it, and to print the two line, which is not happening, (as **metaclass** are inherited?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the `cls` argument (which is the metaclass object) is not passed on when you call `type`, therefore the class object `Y` that is created and returned does not have any reference to the metaclass `Z`.

If you replace the last line in `__new__` with

```
return super(Z, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

then it works. Note that even though `cls` is used in `super` we still have to provide `cls` as an argument as well, since `super` here returns an unbound method (see [here](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=236275) for more).

As an alternative to using super one could use:

```
 return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

The important thing is that we give `cls` (our metaclass object `Z`) to the classmethod `__new__`. The shorter form `type(name, bases, attrs)` fills in `type` itself for the `cls` argument, which is of course wrong. This error is similar to calling an instance method with the wrong `self` argument.

I prefer using `super`, since this is better style.

Comment: Ah, ok, that work. But shouldnt `return super(Z, cls).__new__` be equivalent to `type.__class__.new` whis is equivalent to `type.__new__` which should be same as creating a new class via `type`?

Comment: It is actually not the same, I now address this in my answer. Super does call the `type.__new__` method, but we can then use the correct `cls` argument, which is not possible if we just call `type` directly.