# python 3.2 plugin factory: instantiation from class/metaclass

Tags: python, factory-pattern, metaclass

I'm riffing from the information here: [Metaclass not being called in subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770712/metaclass-not-being-called-in-subclasses)

My problem is that I'm unable to create an instance of an object using this class registry.  If I use "regular" construction methods, then it seems to instantiate objects correctly; but when I try to use the class object associated with registry, then I get an error that I'm passing an incorrect number of arguments.  (Seems to be calling the metaclass **new** and not my constructor...??)

I'm not clear why it's failing, because I thought I should be able to create an instance from the class object by using "callable" syntax.

Seems I'm getting the metaclass put in the registry and not the class itself?  But I don't see an easy way to access the class itself in the **new** call.

Here is my code example, which fails to instantiate a variable 'd':

```
registry = [] # list of subclasses

class PluginMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print(cls)
        print(name)
        registry.append((name, cls))
        return super(PluginMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Plugin(metaclass=PluginMetaclass):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff

# in your plugin modules
class SpamPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff

class BaconPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, stuff):
        self.stuff = stuff

c = SpamPlugin(0)
b = BaconPlugin(0)
mycls = registry[1][1]
d = mycls(0)
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that the `cls` parameter passed to a metaclass constructor is actually a reference to the metaclass and not the class which is being created. Since `__new__` is a classmethod of `PluginMetaclass`, it's associated with that class just like any regular classmethod. You probably want to be registering the newly created class object you're getting from `super(PluginMetaclass, cls).__new__(..)`.

This modified version worked for me on 3.2:

```
class PluginMetaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        print("Called metaclass: %r" % cls)
        print("Creating class with name: %r" % name)
        newclass = super(PluginMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        print("Registering class: %r" % newclass)
        registry.append((name, newclass))
        return newclass
```

and the `print()` calls show what's going on behind the scenes:

```
>>> registry = []
>>>
>>> class Plugin(metaclass=PluginMetaclass):
...     def __init__(self, stuff):
...         self.stuff = stuff
...
Called metaclass: <class '__main__.PluginMetaclass'>
Creating class with name: 'Plugin'
Registering class: <class '__main__.Plugin'>
>>> class SpamPlugin(Plugin):
...     def __init__(self, stuff):
...         self.stuff = stuff
...
Called metaclass: <class '__main__.PluginMetaclass'>
Creating class with name: 'SpamPlugin'
Registering class: <class '__main__.SpamPlugin'>
>>> class BaconPlugin(Plugin):
...     def __init__(self, stuff):
...         self.stuff = stuff
...
Called metaclass: <class '__main__.PluginMetaclass'>
Creating class with name: 'BaconPlugin'
Registering class: <class '__main__.BaconPlugin'>
>>> c = SpamPlugin(0)
>>> b = BaconPlugin(0)
>>> mycls = registry[1][1]
>>> d = mycls(0)
>>> d
<__main__.SpamPlugin object at 0x010478D0>
>>> registry
[('Plugin', <class '__main__.Plugin'>), 
('SpamPlugin', <class '__main__.SpamPlugin'>), 
('BaconPlugin', <class '__main__.BaconPlugin'>)]
```

**Edit:** @drone115b also solved this by using `__init__` instead of `__new__` in `PluginMetaclass`. That's probably the better way to go in most cases.

Comment: Yes, Greg, thanks.  I guess-and-tested for several hours yesterday before happening on an even simpler solution.  Replace __new__ with __init__ and the first parameter is the class name instead of the metaclass name.  The call to super.__init__ will need to have the first argument removed but otherwise it's a fix to the original code that involves changing only the __new__ to __init__.  I certainly wish the docs were clearer on the available interface for metaclasses.

Comment: I should also say, I have a slight personal preference to use init rather than new.  Init is a validation whereas new is an allocation. I don't want to be messing around at a lower level of detail than necessary and I perceive class registration to be more of a validation step.  Either way definitely works, though.

Comment: I agree, `__init__` feels better to me as well, and is definitely more appropriate for this application. I think the need for `__new__` is fairly rare in general, and especially rare for metaclasses.