# Why isn't my metaclass function getting invoked for subclasses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaclass

The Python docs say that the [metaclass of a class can be any callable](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#__metaclass__).  All the examples I see use a class.  Why not use a function?  It's callable, and fairly simple to define.  But it isn't working, and I don't understand why.

Here's my code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __metaclass__(name, base, dict):
        print('inside __metaclass__(%r, ...)' % name)
        return type(name, base, dict)
print(Foo.__metaclass__)
class Bar(Foo):
    pass
print(Bar.__metaclass__)
```

Here's the output:

```
inside __metaclass__('Foo', ...)
<unbound method Foo.__metaclass__>
<unbound method Bar.__metaclass__>
```

The metaclass method is defined for both the parent and child classes.  Why is it only getting called for the parent?  (Yes, I tried using the classmethod and staticmethod decorators for my metaclass, neither works.  Yes, this might seem to be a dup of [Metaclass not being called in subclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770712/metaclass-not-being-called-in-subclasses) but they are a class, not a function, as a metaclass.)

Comment: I add a link to te relevant part of the doc. Please check is this is what you had in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the [precedence rules for `__metaclass__` lookup](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation):

> The appropriate metaclass is determined by the following precedence rules:
>
> - If `dict['__metaclass__']` exists, it is used.
> - Otherwise, **if there is at least one base class, its metaclass is used** (this looks for a `__class__` attribute first and if not found, uses its type).
> - Otherwise, if a global variable named `__metaclass__` exists, it is used.
> - Otherwise, the old-style, classic metaclass (`types.ClassType`) is used.

If we examine `Foo.__class__` we find that it is `<type 'type'>`, which is expected as your metaclass function called `type` to construct `Foo`.

`__class__` is set by `type` to the first parameter of `type.__new__`, which is why in class metaclasses we call `type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)` (or `super(Metaclass, cls).__new__(cls, ...)`). However, we can't do that if the metaclass is a function:

```
>>> def __metaclass__(name, base, dict):
>>>     print('inside __metaclass__(%r, %r, %r)' % (name, base, dict))
>>>     return type.__new__(__metaclass__, name, base, dict)
>>> class Foo(object):
>>>     __metaclass__ = __metaclass__
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type.__new__(X): X is not a type object (function)
```

Similarly, if we try to set `Foo.__class__` to your `__metaclass__` it fails, as the `__class__` attribute must be a class:

```
>>> Foo.__class__ = Foo.__metaclass__.__func__
TypeError: __class__ must be set to new-style class, not 'function' object
```

So, the reason to make metaclasses classes inheriting `type`, as opposed to just callables, is to make them inheritable.

Comment: I don't quite get it. Does the run-time _try_ to set `Foo.__class__` to the given `__metaclass__` at some point ? Or is it the "programmer's responsibility" ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux that happens automatically *if* you call `type.__new__(cls, ...)` (or, equivalently, `super(MyMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, ...)`). I'll clarify, thanks.